# Using a Perl CGI Session in PHP

Tags: php, perl, session, session-variables

Is there anyway to get Perl Cgi session information within PHP? Most of the site I'm working on is programmed in Perl, except for a small portion. This portion uses PHP instead, and I was wondering how I could use the Perl CGI Session information from within PHP.

I was thinking of executing a perl script upon entering the page through exec that verified the session information, but I was hoping there was a better way to access the session variables, preferably one that would work without the use of exec.

Any suggestions?

If it helps, the segment that's in PHP is loaded within an iframe on the page. I'm using Perl's CGI:Session module to create the sessions.

If you need anymore information, just let me know.

Comment: Where does Perl store its session information? In a file? What do the contents of those files look like?

Comment: Which module are you using? `CGI::Session` or `Apache::Session` or something else?

Comment: CGI::Session module, essentially each session creates its own file in a directory.

Comment: @Lusitanian — Perl is going strong. It has had a new major release every year since 2010, a really powerful [OO system](http://moose.iinteractive.com/), a number of web frameworks such as [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) and [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), and a nice [generic webserver interface](http://plackperl.org/) that works with mod_perl, FastCGI and whatever. The two flagship books on Perl, [Learning Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018452.do) and [Programming Perl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) have had new editions in the last year.

Comment: user1464055, show the [constructor](http://p3rl.org/CGI::Session#new-dsn-query-sid-dsn_args-) that creates the CGI::Session object. When seeing the `$dsn` parameter, it is possible to properly discern how/in what format the session is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Session::Serialize::php

You init call would be something like this:

```
my $session = CGI::Session->new( 'serializer:php' );
```

I am not 100% sure on the php side. CGI::Session::Serialize::php uses https://metacpan.org/module/PHP::Session so it may just work automatically with php. If not you will have to point php to the perl session file.

One more edit.

If that does not work you could use https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Session::Serialize::yaml

Then have php parse it http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php